# How to avoid cycles when introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint in a table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I'm using **code-first** approach with **EF Core 6** to construct the database and its tables. The problem is that when I update the database, I get an error regarding cycles or multiple cascade paths. I searched the same questions but none of them could solve my problem.
My entity classes are:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string UserRole { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool CanAccessNotifications { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool CanAccessMessages { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool CanAccessFiles { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool CanAccessPmDatabase { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool CanMakeChangesToPmDatabase { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool CanLocked { get; set; }

    //Navigation properties
    public virtual CostCenter CostCenter { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PmSchedule> PmSchedules { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceType
{
    [Key]
    public int ServiceTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;

    //Navigation properties
    public virtual List<PmDataSet> PmDataSets { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PmSchedule> PmSchedules { get; set; }
}

public class PmSchedule
{
    [Key]
    public long PmScheduleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long PmNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime ScheduledStartDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime ScheduledEndDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string MainFileName { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string? UploadedFileName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int MainUploader { get; set; }
    public int? Uploader { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? CompletionDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string? Status { get; set; }

    //Navigation properties
    public virtual CostCenter CostCenter { get; set; }
    public virtual ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; }
}

public class PmDataSet
{
    [Key]
    public long PmDataSetId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long PmNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime ScheduledStartDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime ScheduledEndDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string WorkOrderNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Activity { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ActualDuration { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int StandardDuration { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Executor { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string? Expaination { get; set; }


    //Navigation properties
    public virtual ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; }
    public virtual CostCenter CostCenter { get; set; }
    public virtual Equipment Equipment { get; set; }
}

public class Equipment
{
    [Key]
    public long EquipmentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string EquipmentCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string EquipmentTitle { get; set; }

    //Navigation properties
    public virtual CostCenter CostCenter { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PmDataSet> PmDataSets { get; set; }
}

public class CostCenter
{
    [Key]
    public int CostCenterId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;


    //Navigation properties
    public virtual List<PmDataSet>? PmDataSets { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PmSchedule>? PmSchedules { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Equipment>? Equipments { get; set; }
    public virtual List<User>? Users { get; set; }
}
```

My context class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    }
```

I get the following error when update the database:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
> 'FK_PmDataSets_Equipments_EquipmentId' on table 'PmDataSets' may cause
> cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON
> UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not
> create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add some extra config like this :

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
{   
    var pmConfig = mb.Entity<PmDataSet>();
    pmConfig.HasOne(n => n.Equipment).WithMany(n => n.PmDataSets).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
}
```

the problem is your Equipment model or/and some others already has at least one cascade delete relation,
so if you add another cascade delete relation there will be a chain deletion if one of these entities got deleted.
so you need to tell ef that some/none of these relations are not cascading while deleting.

(A) <-- cascade --> (B)

(B) <-- cascade --> (C)
so there will be a logical cascade between A and C, that is not arbitrary.

with a little playing with that config you will solve your problem ;)

-------- update
to answer the commented question u can go by ef convictions:

```
public User MainUploader { get; set; }
[Required]
public int MainUploaderId { get; set; }
public User Uploader { get; set; }
public int? UploaderId { get; set; }
```

you also can use [ForeignKey("fkName")] annotation if you want to use another way of naming your properties,
or use fluent API ForeignKey(a=> a.something) method or its overlods.

Comment: i forgot to say, OnDelete.Cascade is the default behaviour

Comment: Thanks. How can I have two FK in table `PmSchedule` and link `UserId` to both `MainUploader` and `Uploader` columns?

Comment: there is several ways to config that, but the easiest way is to go by EF convection, I will append it to answer